# Dump YAML-like key names of Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

What's a convenient way to get a list of all `Hash` keys (with nesting) separated by dots?

Given I have a hash:

```
{ level1: { level21: { level31: 'val1', 
                       level32: 'val2' }, 
            level22: 'val3' } 
}
```

Desired output (array of strings) which represents all key paths in a hash:

```
level1.level21.level31
level1.level21.level32
level1.level22
```

My current solution:

```
class HashKeysDumper
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.map do |k, v|
      if v.is_a? Hash
        keys = dump(v)
        keys.map { |k1| [k, k1].join('.') }
      else
        k.to_s
      end
    end.flatten
  end
end
```

It also available as [gist](https://gist.github.com/4184731) (with specs).

Comment: Please don't link to your code, instead, add a summarized version of it to your question, properly formatted, so we can quickly access it, instead of having to chase it down. This helps us help you, and it also helps keep your question relevant. If that link goes down your question will be unusable to people looking for answers to a similar question in the future.

Comment: Actually, your solution looks good to me. Is there anything specific you wanted to change about it? (and I agree with @theTinMan that you should add it to your question).

Comment: @MarkThomas I am actually satisfied with my solution, but curious if it's possible to do this job cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you mean by cleaner, but here's a *smaller* version that…

1. Will work on subclasses Hashes or Hash-alikes
2. Extends Hash, making it *look* cleaner in your code.

   ```
   class Hash
     def keydump
       map{|k,v|v.keydump.map{|a|"#{k}.#{a}"} rescue k.to_s}.flatten
     end
   end
   ```

results:

```
{ level1: { level21: { level31: 'val1', 
                       level32: 'val2' }, 
            level22: 'val3' } 
}.keydump
=> ["level1.level21.level31", "level1.level21.level32", "level1.level22"]
```

Comment: thanks @Mark but I actually prefer not to monkey-patch core classes (at least unless Ruby 2.0 is out with refinements). So keeping everything in a separate class/module is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: I like your solution Mark, nice and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my vision of this:

```
h = { 'level1' => { 'level2' => { 'level31' => 'val1', 'level32' => 'val2' } } }

class Hash
  def nested_keys
    self.inject([]) { |f, (k,v)| f += [k, v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.nested_keys : []] }.flatten
  end
end

keys = h.nested_keys

p keys
#=> ["level1", "level2", "level31", "level32"]

k1, k2 = keys.shift, keys.shift

puts [k1, k2, keys.shift].join('.')
#=> level1.level2.level31

puts [k1, k2, keys.shift].join('.')
#=> level1.level2.level32
```

#### [Here is a Working Demo](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=dump-yaml-like-key-names-of-hash-in-ruby.rb&run=true)

Comment: @Andrey, see updated answer please. First version was a bit clunked by rush... :) Is it of some help for you?

Comment: thanks @slivu but I am not sure if this actually will work for a more complex hashes like this one { level1: { level21: 'val', level22: { level31: 'value1', level32: 'value2' } } }

Comment: it does return all keys of a hash as an array. hash can be of any nesting level. is not this what you asked in the question?

Comment: what I want is to get all key paths. I've updated my question with a slightly better description.

Answer (score 0):

I just committed some code to [RubyTree](https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree) that adds `from_hash()` which would allow you to do this:

```
require 'rubytree'

Tree::TreeNode.from_hash(hash).each_leaf.map{|n| "#{n.name}.#{n.parentage.map(&:name).reverse.join('.')}" }

=> ["level1.level21.level31", "level1.level21.level32", "level1.level22"]
```

Aside from the gem require, it's a one-liner :)